# Is there a way to target all Font Awesome icons and align them center?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to somehow target the class in:

```css
<i class="fas fa-tree fa-4x"></i>
```

and center the content horizontal

```css
fas {
  align-content: center;
}
```

I can't figure something out though. Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

This is the context:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-4 mb-1">
  <i class="fas fa-tree fa-4x"></i>
  <h4 class="my-4" font-weight-bold>The Park</h4>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: alignment need a reference. Align based on what? we need more context

Comment: Hello, you want to align them horizontally or vertically?

Comment: One more thing there is a typo in your code. When you are referencing class in CSS you should add period or dot before the class name. like `.fas {
  align-content: center;
}`

Comment: I updated the question, it was quite badly written.

Answer (score -1):

First way: when you only want to center the icon.

```css
.cutomsClass  {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.fas {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-4 mb-1 d-flex cutomsClass">
  <i class="fas fa-tree fa-4x"></i>
  <h4 class="my-4" font-weight-bold>The Park</h4>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Second way:
if you want to center everything along with icon,

```css
.cutomsClass  {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-4 mb-1 d-flex cutomsClass">
  <i class="fas fa-tree fa-4x"></i>
  <h4 class="my-4" font-weight-bold>The Park</h4>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```